# android - SQLite rawQuery causing problems

Tags: android, sqlite

posted below is the code that I'm having problems with. I have narrowed the issue down to the `cursor = db.rawQuery()` statement.

Why is the statement incorrect? The setup of the database *seems* correct, but I cannot seem to query it. I have tried both `db.query()` and `db.rawQuery()`.

Because the app simply crashes when run on a physical device (the Motorola Atrix that I'm using for testing) is it possible that a few models don't ship with SQLite?

```
public class Database {
    private static final String ID_DATE = "id_date";
    private static final String ROUND = "round";
    private static final String CATEGORY = "category";
    private static final String VALUE = "value";
    private static final String ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "clues";
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/es.foo.bar/databases/" + DB_NAME;
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private Context c = null;
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            this.c = context;
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                InputStream is = c.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer);
                }
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {  }
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int old_v, int new_v) {
        }
    }
    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper helpme;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    public Database(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }
    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        helpme = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = helpme.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() { helpme.close(); }
    public boolean askfordata() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from clues where question match \'foo\'", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the main (and only) activity for the app:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Database db = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView hw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloworld);
        db = new Database(this);
        db.open();
        if (db != null) {
            if (db.askfordata()) hw.setText("Worked.");
        }
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        db.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

ADB logcat output:

`01-20 23:35:27.183 22155 22155 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-20 23:35:27.183 22155 22155 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.foo.bar/es.foo.bar.Main}:
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
    no such table: clues: , while compiling: select * from clues where question match 'foo'`

Does that mean that my table was never created? I moved my table from my `/assets/` folder to the proper location in the `onCreate` method. I can use `sqlite3` to view the `.db` file on my computer, and list the tables there. That shows all my tables:

`clues  clues_content   clues_segdir clues_segments`

Note: I left out the `import`s to save space. Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: could you please post the logcat/stack trace information? you haven't provided too much information here...

Comment: also if you have your app installed and you have recently made changes to the database, android could be caching the old database thus giving you an error... won't know for sure if this is the case until you give us some error logs :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt advice.

Comment: post it in your question so other people can help too!

Comment: It looks like your table isn't being created.

Comment: I don't like copy algorithm because on last pass it may write extra bytes to the output file.
 Can you run the query using sqlite3 tool (everything on computer)? Results?

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clues (question TEXT, answer TEXT)", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

is required to actually create the table

Comment: But the database already exists. I need to query it for data now.

Comment: according to your logcat the database exists but the table does not. Tables are stored inside the database, creating a database does not create a table. --android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: clues:

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the database in your assets folder to make sure it has been created correctly? You can look at it quickly with a tool like the [Sqlite plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

**Update**

Modify this code:

```
InputStream is = c.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
```

to be:

```
InputStream is = c.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
this.getReadableDatabase();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
```

I think your copy is failing, you just missed it in the logs.  Uninstall your app before you try again.

Comment: I have checked and checked again, everything _seems_ to be in order. I'm guessing there's an issue with the code itself.

Comment: well, if the query `select * from clues` returns an error that the table clues does not exist then I can only assume that it does not exist.  Have you pulled the copy the app creates of the DB from the device to verify that the copy is correct?

Comment: I can't seem to get access using ADB pull. Permission is denied.

Comment: yeah, you can't do it from a non-rooted device.. you'll need to run the app in the emulator and run adb -e pull